# Show $GCD(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots , a_n)$ is the least positive integer that can be expressed in the form $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+ \ldots +a_nx_n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

> Given $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots , a_n$ not all zero, show $\gcd(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots , a_n)$ is the least positive integer that can be expressed in the form $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+ \ldots +a_nx_n$. Also deduce $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+ \ldots +a_nx_n = b$ has solutions $\iff \gcd(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots , a_n)|b$.

I know that $ax+by=n$ has integer solutions $\iff \gcd(a,b)|n$.
I'll need to use induction to show $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+ \ldots +a_nx_n = \gcd(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots , a_n)$ has solutions, and then I will be able to say that as $\gcd(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots , a_n) | a_1x_1+a_2x_2+ \ldots +a_nx_n $ for any $x_1,x_2, x_3 \ldots x_n$ then $c \leq \gcd(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots , a_n)$ and $c \geq \gcd(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots , a_n)$, and thus $c=\gcd(a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots , a_n)$.

Comment: are you familiar with general algebra?

Comment: I know the basics of general algebra

Answer (score 6):

Here is a *conceptual* way to prove [Bezout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) for the gcd. The set $\rm\,S\,$ of integers of form $\rm\,a_1\,x_1 + \cdots + a_n x_n,\ x_j\in \mathbb Z\,$ is $\rm\color{#c00}{closed\ under\ subtraction}$ so, by the Lemma below, every positive $\rm\,s\in S\,$ is divisible by $\rm\,d := $ least positive $\rm\in S.\,$  Therefore $\rm\,a_j\in S$ $\,\Rightarrow\,$ $\rm d\mid a_j,\,$ i.e. $\rm\,d\,$ is a *common* divisor of all $\rm\,a_j,\,$ necessarily *greatest* by $\rm\ c\mid \color{#0a0}{a_{\,j}}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\,c\mid d = \color{#0a0}{a_{\,1}}\,{\it x_1}\!+\!\cdots\!+\!\color{#0a0}{a_{\,n}}\,{\it x_n}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\,c\le d.\,$

**Note** $\rm \ s\in S\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid s\,$ means $\rm \, S\subseteq d\Bbb Z.\,$ Reversely $\rm\,S\supseteq d\Bbb Z\,$ by $\rm\,d\in S\,$ and $\,\rm S\,$ closed under integer scalings: $\rm\ k \sum a_j x_j = \sum a_j (k x_j)\in S.\, $ Therefore: $\rm\, S = d\Bbb Z,\,$ i.e.

$$\rm\bbox[6px,border:1px solid #c00]{ a_1 \Bbb Z +\cdots+a_n \Bbb Z\, =\, \gcd(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\Bbb Z}\qquad$$

**Lemma** $\ \ $ Let $\,\rm S\ne\emptyset \,$ be a set of integers $>0\,$ $\rm\color{#c00}{closed\ under\ subtraction}$ $> 0,\,$ i.e. for all $\rm\,n,m\in S, \,$ $\rm\ n > m\ \Rightarrow\  n-m\, \in\, S.\,$  Then the least $\rm\:\ell\in S\,$ divides every element of $\,\rm S.$

**Proof** ${\bf\ 1}\,\  $ If not there is a least nonmultiple $\rm\,n\in S,\,$ contra  $\rm\,n-\ell \in S\,$ is a nonmultiple of $\rm\,\ell.$

**Proof** ${\bf\ 2}\,\rm\,\ \   S\,$ closed under subtraction $\rm\,\Rightarrow\,S\,$ closed under remainder (mod), when it is $\ne 0,$ since mod is simply repeated subtraction, i.e. $\rm\ a\ mod\ b\, =\, a - k b\, =\, a\!-\!b\!-\!b\!-\cdots\! -\!b.\,$ Therefore $\rm\,n\in S\,$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm\, (n\ mod\ \ell) = 0,\,$ else it is in $\,\rm S\,$ and smaller than $\rm\,\ell,\,$ contra minimality of $\rm\,\ell.$

**Remark** $\ $ In a nutshell, two applications of induction yield the following inferences

$ \rm\begin{eqnarray}\rm S\ closed\ under\ {\bf subtraction} &\:\Rightarrow\:&\rm S\ closed\ under\ {\bf mod} = remainder = repeated\ subtraction \\
&\:\Rightarrow\:&\rm S\ closed\ under\ {\bf gcd} = repeated\ mod\ (Euclid's\ algorithm) \end{eqnarray}$

Interpreted constructively, this yields the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/23500) for the gcd. Namely, $ $ starting from the two elements of $\rm\,S\,$ that we know: $\rm\ a \,=\, 1\cdot a + 0\cdot b,\ \ b \,=\, 0\cdot a + 1\cdot b,\, $ we search for the least element of $\rm\,S\,$ by repeatedly subtracting elements of $\,\rm S\,$ to produce smaller elements of $\rm\,S\,$ (while keeping track of each elements linear representation in terms of $\rm\,a\,$ and $\rm\,b).\:$ This is essentially the *subtractive* form of the Euclidean GCD algorithm (vs. the  mod / remainder form), where each reduction / descent step employs subtraction (vs. iterated subtraction = mod).

The underlying algebraic structure of $\rm\,S\,$ (closure under addition and scalings) is clarified conceptually on study of *ideals* of rings, where the above proof (in remainder vs. subtractive form) [generalizes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1185396/242) to show that Euclidean domains are PIDs.

**Beware** that this *linear* representation of the the gcd need not hold true in all domains where gcds exist, e.g. in the UFD $\rm\:D = \mathbb Q[x,y]\:$ of polynomials in $\rm\:x,y\:$ with rational coefficients we have $\rm\:gcd(x,y) = 1\:$ but there are no $\rm\:f(x,y),\: g(x,y)\in D\:$ such that $\rm\:x\:f(x,y) + y\:g(x,y) = 1;\:$ indeed, if so, then evaluating at $\rm\:x = 0 = y\:$ yields $\:0 = 1.$

Comment: Very nice answer as usual. One doubt: why does $c \mid a,b$ imply $c \mid d$? Is it because we can always write $d = ya + zb$ for some $y, z \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Anant $\,\ c\mid a_i\,$ so $\,c\mid a_i x_i,\,$ so $\ c\mid a_1x_1 +\cdots + a_n x_n,\,$ i.e. the set of multiples of $\,c\,$ are closed under addition and interger multiples $\, x\to kx,\ k\in\Bbb Z,\,$ i.e. they form an ideal (note: I fixed one sentence that I overlooked converting from the binary  to $n$-ary case).

Comment: Clear now, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**Outline:** The induction step goes as follows. Suppose that for a particular integer $k$, and integers $a_1,\dots,a_k$, there exist integers $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k$ such that
$$\gcd(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k)=x_1a_1+\cdots+x_ka_k.\tag{1}$$
We want to show that there exist integers $y_1,\dots,y_k,y_{k+1}$ such that
$$\gcd(a_1,\dots,a_k,a_{k+1})=y_1a_1+\cdots+y_ka_k+y_{k+1}a_{k+1}.$$

We need the fact that 
$$\gcd(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k,a_{k+1})=\gcd(\gcd(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k),a_{k+1}).$$
This is not particularly hard to prove.

So by a familiar result, there exist integers $s$ and $t$ such that
$$\gcd(a_1,\dots,a_k,a_{k+1})=s\gcd(a_1,\dots,a_k)+ta_{k+1}.\tag{2}$$
Substitute the right-hand side of (1) for $\gcd(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k)$ in (2).

After we have proved this representation theorem, the rest is straightforward. Since the gcd $d$ of $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$ is representable, every integer multiple of $d$ is representable. The converse is clear, any representable number is a multiple of $d$.

Answer (score 1):

The subgroup of $\Bbb Z$, $a_1\Bbb Z + \cdots + a_n\Bbb Z$ has the form
$d\Bbb Z$. $d$ is the least positive integer that can be expressed in the form you look for.

Now write
$$d = a_1 x_1 + \cdots + a_n x_n$$ and divide by $ \gcd(a_1,\dots,a_n) $; this shows that 
$$
 \gcd(a_1,\dots,a_n) |d
$$
Then, the Bezout identity and an induction prove that $$
 \gcd(a_1,\dots,a_n) \in a_1\Bbb Z + \cdots + a_n\Bbb Z
= d\Bbb Z$$

that is, $d|\gcd(a_1,\dots,a_n)$. Eventually,
$$
d=  \gcd(a_1,\dots,a_n)
$$