# Using extended Euklid to find a linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra

I got the following equation where you have to find possible integers for $m$ and $n$ that satisfy:

$$144n+136m=4$$

What I tried was to use the Extended Euklidean Algorithm. But it gives me the greatest common divisor which is 8 for the following combination:

$144*1+136*1=8$ where $m=1$ and $n=1$

Is there any way to find a linear combination of $m$ and $n$ that satisfies the equation above?

Or, is there no solution for this at all?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. For any integers $a,b$, the set $\bigl\{ua+vb\;\vert\:u,v\in\mathbf Z\bigr\}$ is the set of multiples of $\gcd(a,b)$. As this g.c.d. is $8$, you only can obtain multiples of $8$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ Cancelling $\,4\,$ yields $\, 26n+34m = 1.\,$ LHS is even, contra RHS is odd.

**Remark** $\ $ [Generally](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/718833/242) $\ a\Bbb Z\! +\! b\Bbb Z\overset{\rm Bezout} = \gcd(a,b) \Bbb Z\,$ so $\,ax\!+\!by = c\,$ is solvable $\iff \gcd(a,b)\mid c$

Comment: Ok, so its not possible to find a combination?

Comment: @Ovomaltine Right, since if a solution $\,m,n\,$ exists then, by  the my first equation above, there is an integer that is both even and odd, a contradiction.