# Is Bezout's lemma enough to confirm the GCD of a number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is Bezout's lemma enough to confirm the GCD of a number?

So suppose we have $$ax+by=z$$ does this mean $$\gcd(a,b)=z$$

Comment: No, of course not. Say if hcf of a and b is 1, then there are integers $(x,y)$ such that $ax+by=1$, but then there are also integers $(2x,2y)$ such that $a\cdot (2x)+b\cdot (2y)=2$. This doesn't mean the hcf is 2. However, if z is the smallest positive integer that is of the form $ax+by$, then it is the hcf.

Comment: The HCF of $a$ and $b$ is unique, but there are any number of linear combinations of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Note: I changed HCF to GCD in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I note that $\mathrm{hcf}$ is usually denoted as $\gcd$ (*greatest common divisor*). Now from
$$ax+by = z$$
we can only see that $\gcd(a,b) \mid z$ (i.e. $z$ is a multiple of $\gcd(a,b)$) and by Bezout's lemma there exist *some* $(x,y)$ such that $z=\gcd(a,b)$.
You can't infer anything else about $\gcd(a,b)$ from this, not even if you force $\gcd(x,y)=1$. For example $x=y=1$ gives $z=a+b$. There is not much you could say about the $\gcd$ of some numbers only knowing their sum.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:
$$ 1\cdot 2 + 1\cdot 3 = 5,$$
and so 
$$\gcd (1,1) = 5.$$
You might try almost any combination of numbers and check for yourself the validity of your statement.

Answer (score 0):

A *common* divisor $\,c\mid a,b\,$ is *greatest* if it can be written in linear form $\,c = j a + k b,\,$ since then $\,d\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid ja+kb = c,\,$ so $\, d\le c.\,$ Conversely, by [Bezout,](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/718827/242) we know every greatest common divisor can be expressed as such a linear combination.

But only the *least* positive such linear combination of $\,a,b\,$ equals the gcd. Indeed, such linear combinations are preserved by scaling by arbitrary integers, so any multiple of the gcd is also such a linear combination. Further, one can show that the integers of the form $\ ja + kb \ $ are precisely all integer multiples of the gcd, i.e. $\ a \Bbb Z + b\Bbb Z\, =\, \gcd(a,b)\Bbb Z.\,$ Said equivalently, there exist integers $\,x,y\,$ such that $\ a x + by = c \iff\gcd(a,b)\mid c,\,$ see [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290965/242)