# Using gcd Bezout identity to solve linear Diophantine equations and congruences, and compute modular inverses and fractions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, inverse, linear-diophantine-equations

Isn't finding the inverse of $a$, that is, $a'$ in $aa'\equiv1\pmod{m}$ equivalent to solving the diophantine equation $aa'-mb=1$, where the unknowns are $a'$ and $b$? I have seem some answers on this site (where the extended Euclidean Algorithm is mentioned mainly) as well as looked up some books but there is no mention of this. Am I going wrong somewhere or is this a correct method of finding modular inverses? Also can't we find the Bézout's coefficients by solving the corresponding diophantine equation instead of using the extended Euclidean Algorithm?

Comment: Yes this is correct. Consider the equation $aa'-mb=1$ modulo $m$.

Comment: Extended Euclidean algorithm  is much faster  (and simpler) to perform!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's well-known and  occurs here many times, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2326680/242) where it is special case $\,b\! =\! 1\,$ below of the solvability criterion for a general linear congruence
$\quad\ \, \exists\, x\in\Bbb Z\!:\  ax\equiv b\pmod{\! m}\!\iff\! \exists\, x,y\in\Bbb Z\!:\ ax\!+\!my = b\!\overset{\rm\ Bezout}\iff{\color{#c00}{\overbrace{\gcd(a,m)}^{\large d}}}\mid b$

**Proof** $\ \ (\Rightarrow)\ \ ax\equiv b\pmod{\!m}\Rightarrow ax\!+\!my = b\,$ for $\,y\in\Bbb Z\,$ so $\,\color{#c00}{d\mid a,m}\Rightarrow\,d\mid \color{#c00}ax\!+\!\color{#c00}my = b.\ $
$(\Leftarrow)\ \ $ By [Bezout](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/203450/242): $\,\exists\,\bar x,\bar y\in\Bbb Z\!:\,$ $\,a\bar x\!+\!m\bar y = d\,$ $\Rightarrow\, a(\color{darkorange}c\bar x)\!+\!\color{#0a0}m(c\bar y) = b,\,$ via scaling by $\,\color{darkorange}{c :=} \color{#c00}{b/d},\ $ hence reducing the prior equation $\!\bmod \color{#0a0}m\,$ yields $\,a(\color{darkorange}c\bar x)\equiv b\pmod{\!\color{#0a0}m},\,$ so we choose $\,x\equiv\color{darkorange}c\bar x\,$ (said in congruence language: $ $ to compute $\!\bmod m\!:\ x\equiv \color{#c48}b/a\:\!\equiv \:\!\color{#c48}{\color{darkorange}c\:\!\:\!d}/a\,$ scale $\,\bar x \equiv \color{#c00}{d}/a\,$ by $\,\color{darkorange}c)$.

**Remark** $ $ The special case $\,b=1\,$ above is ubiquitous, i.e. we may compute the modular inverse  $\,x\equiv a^{-1}\bmod{m}\:$ by solving $\,ax+my = 1,\,$ e.g. via [*forward!* extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/616893/242).

Switching back-and-forth between a linear congruence and its associated linear Diophantine equation is something so *basic* and *ubiquitous*  that it is rarely *explicitly* mentioned - just as for  use of other basic laws (associative, commutative, distributive etc.)

By the above arrows, computing [modular fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) (= inverses when $\,b=1)\,$ is *equivalent* to solving the associated linear Diophantine equation.

There are various ways to solve such congruences and equations, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3434557/solve-the-8n9-equiv-0-pmod1163-n-in-mathbb-n/3434593#3434593) & [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2367841/what-is-the-best-way-to-solve-modular-arithmetic-equations-such-as-9x-equiv-33/2368266#2368266) for a handful of methods applicable when the solution is unique.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242) for the general method when the solution is not unique, which includes a handy  *fractional* view of above, and its use in the *extended* Euclidean algorithm. As is often the case, use of fractions may yield  significant simplification and conceptual insight.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2060729/242) for the equivalence of the above and CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: How does one show the inverse multiple of a modulo m is unique and what exactly does it mean for it to be unique? For example solving $3x\equiv 7 \pmod{10}$ I found multiple inverses of 3 modulo 10. In fact, all of these inverses multiples satisfy the Bezout's identity given by $\gcd(3,10)=1=3s+10t$. For example, $3(7)+10(-2)=1, 3(17)+10(-5)=1, 3(27)+10(-8)=1$, and so forth. How exactly is say, $a^{-1}=7$ "unique" if $a^{-1}=17, 27, \cdots$ work just fine as well?

Comment: I ask because in Kenneth Rosen's book on Discrete Mathmeatics and its Applications, it is claimed on section 4.4.2 that for $ax\equiv b \pmod{m}$ with $\gcd(a,m)=1$, there is a "...unique positive integer $\bar a$ less than m that is an inverse of a modulo m and every other inverse of a modulo m congruent to $\bar a$ modulo m." Proving that this is "unique" was left as an exercise.

Comment: @Lex_i  An inverse $\,a'\,$ is unique $\bmod m$ means that if $\,a'$ and $\,a''$ are inverses then $\,a'\equiv a''\pmod{m},\,$  i.e. uniqueness of roots of $\,ax\equiv 1\pmod{m}.\,$ The uniqueness proof [is easy](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033516/242).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can find the Bézout's coefficients without using the Euclidean algorithm.

An algorithm can be constructed by 'lifting' some algebra/logic from the [Wikipedia existence proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity#Proof).

Our algorithm operates on the input

$\tag 1 ax+by=z$

as follows:

If $z \mid a$ and $z \mid b$ the algorithm terminates and $\text{(1)}$ is the solution.

If $z \not\mid a$ the algorithm transforms the equation to

$\tag 2 au+bv=r, \text{ where } a = zq + r \;\text{(euclidean division)} \land \big[u = 1-qx \big] \land \big[v = -qy\big]$

and repeats with $u \text{ replacing } x$ and $v \text{ replacing } y$ and and $r \text{ replacing } z$.

If $z \not\mid b$ the algorithm transforms the equation to

$\tag 3 au+bv=r, \text{ where } b = zq + r \;\text{(euclidean division)} \land \big[u = -qx \big] \land \big[v = 1-qy\big]$

and repeats with $u \text{ replacing } x$ and $v \text{ replacing } y$ and and $r \text{ replacing } z$.

You can assume that $a \gt 0$ and initialize the input to the algorithm as the equation

$\quad a(1) + b(0) = (a) ::: a(x) + b(y) = (z)$

Observe that the algorithm iterates on $\text3{-tuples}$ until the desired form is obtained.

Example: Construct the Bézout's identity for $a = 12$ and $b=42$.

$\quad 12\,(1) + 42\,(0) = (12)$ and with $42$, $q = 3$ and $r=6$
$\quad 12\,(-3) + 42\,(1) = (6)$ and with $42$, $q = 6$ and $r=6$
$\quad 12\,(18) + 42\,(-5) = (6)$ and the algorithm stops on the Bézout's identity