# Please help me with this Abstract Algebra question

Tags: abstract-algebra

I do not know where to start from this. All I know is a & n are relatively prime so a has an inverse mod n and a belong to Zn. How can I make a connection from this fact to where it said $a^{|u(n)|}$ ? Any thought on this please?

Prove: if gcd(a,n) = 1 then $a^{|u(n)|}$(mod n) = 1 (mod n)

Prove: if $a^{|u(n)|}$(mod n) = 1 (mod n) then gcd(a,n) = 1

Recall: |u(n)| is the order of the group of units modulo n.

This is an if and only if statement so I need to prove both ways.
Please help me on how to get start on this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  In order for your MathJax commands to be effective, they must be surrounded by `$` signs.  `$a^{|u(n)|}$` comes out as $a^{|u(n)|}$

Comment: You'll find that questions that say only, "Here's my problem, how do I solve it?" don't get a very good response.  What do you know about this problem?  Any thoughts?

Comment: For the 2nd proof use $\,a^k\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, a\,$ invertible $\Rightarrow \gcd(a,n)=1\,$ by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290965/242) from the 2nd dupe link. Please search before posting questions. These are FAQs with many prior answers.