# prove that $a^{N-1} \not\equiv 1(\bmod N)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I need to prove the following:
$$\begin{aligned}
&\text { Prove that } a^{N-1} \not\equiv 1(\bmod N) \text { if } \operatorname{gcd}(a, N)>1, \text { where } a, N \in \mathbb{Z} \text { and }\\
&N \geq 1
\end{aligned}$$

---

My attempt on a solution.
set $d=gcd(a,N)>1$. Since $d$ divides a, we have:
$$a\equiv 0 (\bmod d)$$
using this repeatedly we have:
$$a^{N-1}\equiv 0 (\bmod d)$$

Since $d\mid N$ does that imply:
$$\implies a^{N-1}\equiv 0 (\bmod N)$$?

---

I'm not quite convinced that this is true. If $d\mid a^{N-1}$ and $d \mid N$. Does that imply $N \mid a^{N-1}$? And how should I use the assumption $d>1$?.

I believe it would be obvious if it was the other way around. if $N \mid d$

Comment: The implication doesn't hold, but try to derive a contradiction: what happens if $a^{N-1}\equiv 1\pmod N$? How does it contradict $a^{N-1}\equiv 0\pmod d$?

Comment: Because of $\gcd(a,N)>1$, there must be a prime $p$ dividing $a$ and $N$. $$a^{N-1}\equiv 1\mod N$$ implies $$a^{N-1}\equiv 1\mod p$$ contradicting $$a^{N-1}\equiv 0\mod p$$

Comment: You can also apply this for $d:=\gcd(a,N)>1$ instead of $p$.

Comment: @player3236 What is wrong with the following proof, where I don't really use $d>1$ for anything.  

Let $d=gcd(a,N)>1$. assume for contradiction that $a^{N-1}\equiv 1(\bmod N)$.   Since $d\mid N$ this implies $$a^{N-1}\equiv 1(\bmod d)$$ which is a contradiction. Since $d\mid a$ implies $a\equiv 0 (\bmod d)$ which again implies $$a^{N-1}\equiv 0 (\bmod d) \not\equiv 1 (\bmod d)$$

Comment: If $d=1$ you could say that $0\equiv1\pmod d$.

Comment: Special case $\,x = a^{N-2},\, b=1\,$ in $\,ax\equiv b\pmod{\!N}\,$ is solvable $\iff \gcd(a,n)\mid b,\,$ by the dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that, in fact, there exists some integer $k$ such that $$a^{N-1}=kN+1$$ Since $d\mid a\implies d\mid a^{N-1}$ and $d\mid N\implies d\mid kN$ we infer that $d\mid 1$, but this is absurd if $d>1$.

Comment: Special case $\,x = a^{N-2},\, b=1\,$ in $\,ax\equiv b\pmod{\!N}\,$ is solvable $\iff \gcd(a,N)\mid b,\,$ by [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290965/242)