# Irreducible polynomial written as $ap + bq$

Tags: polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

I want to know if the following proposition is true or false :

Let $p$ and $q$ $\in \mathbb Q[X]$ two polynomials of degree $\geq 1$ and let $g$ $\in \mathbb Q[X]$ an irreducible unitary polynomial, with deg(g) $\geq 1$ such that $\exists$ two polynomials $a$ and $b$ $\in \mathbb Q[X]$ with $g = ap + bq$. Then $g = gcd(p,q)$.

I have the feeling that it is true with a few tests but I don't know how to prove it and I feel like something is wrong with the fact that we are $\mathbb Q[X]$. What if we are $\mathbb R[X]$ ?

(I also have that $x-\frac74=(\frac18x+\frac14)(x-1)-(\frac18x-\frac12)(x-3)$ but $x-\frac74$ does not seem to be $(x-1)$ and $(x-3)$'s gcd).

Comment: By [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290965/242), $\,py + qz = g\,$ is solvable for $\,y,z\in \Bbb Q[x]\!\iff\! \gcd(p,q)\mid g,\,$ which is *not* equivalent to $\,\gcd(p,q) = g,\,$ e.g. it's solvable when $\,\gcd(p,q)=1\neq g\ $ (here we assume for convenience both $g$ and gcds are normalized to be monic, i.e. lead coef $=1,\,$ else you need to compare gcds not by equality but by associateness).

Answer (score 1):

You have a good counterexample, so the proposition doesn't hold.

There's no particular reason to expect that it *would* hold, either. The claim is a **converse** of [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikhttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identityipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) for $\mathbb Q[X]$, but nobody says such a converse has to hold anywhere.

In fact, the corresponding converse doesn't even hold in $\mathbb Z$: There we know well that $ap+bq$ can be any *multiple* of the gcd of $p$ and $q$, and just because $ap+bq$ is prime (that is, irreducible) doesn't mean that this multiple needs to be the gcd itself. Namely, it might be that $p$ and $q$ are coprime, in which case *anything* in $\mathbb Z$ can be written as $ap+bq$.

That's essentially what goes on in your counterexample too: $\gcd_{\mathbb Q[X]}(x-1,x-3)=1$, so you can get *anything you want* as a sum of polynomial multiples of those two factors. Just pick any $g$ and let $a=\frac12g$ and $b=-\frac12g$ ...

Working over $\mathbb R[X]$ wouldn't make a difference here.

Comment: +1. If we amend the proposition to include $\deg (\gcd (p,q))>0$ and $g\ne 0$ then it is true: Let $h=\gcd (p,q).$ Let $p=(p^*)(h)$ and $q=(q^*)(h).$ Then $g=(ap^*+bq^*)(h)$ is (by assumption) non-$0$ and irreducible but $\deg (h)>0$ so $ap^*+bq^*$ must be a non-$0$ constant.