# I got mixed up by the use of triple bar vs equals sign in linear congruences. Is it worth asking the professor for a regrade?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, examples-counterexamples

On an exam I recently took, I was asked the following question:

What are the number of solutions to the equation:

$ax = b$ (mod $m$) when gcd($b,m$) = 1 and gcd($a,m$) = $d$ > 1

I know this is entirely sematic, but I was confused when I saw them use = instead of ≡ in the equation. For this reason, I interpreted the right-hand side to be a specific value $(b\%m)$ and stated there was one solution. In reality, there are no solutions as the expression ax + km is always a multiple of d and b is not.

What I really want to know is if my interpretation was valid at all, and if it is worth asking the professor for a regrade in the context of ≡ vs = or if I just take the L.

Comment: In any case there is no solution...

Comment: $ax = (b\bmod m) = b - qm\,$ so $\,d\mid a,m\Rightarrow d\mid b,\,$ contra hypothesis. So that too has no solution. Or use $\,ax = (b\bmod m)\Rightarrow ax\equiv b\pmod{m}$

Comment: @BillDubuque What about for the case where gcd(a,m) = d and d|b?

Comment: $ax\equiv b\pmod{m}$ is solvable $\iff \gcd(a,m)\mid b,\,$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290965/242).