# What does the relative primality of $a$ and $n$ say about the existence of an inverse for $[a]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

I have a potential solution for this problem, though I am unsure it is entirely correct and am positive it is inelegantly stated and could use some help tidying it up (if it is indeed the correct logic):

I started by identifying the definitions of relative primality and the congruence class of $a$ modulo $n$

1. $a$ and $n$ relatively prime means: $\exists$$s,t \in \mathbb{Z}$ $|$ $as + nt = 1$
2. $[a] = \{b \in \mathbb{Z} \mid a \equiv b \pmod n\} = \{a + kn\mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

We can say, if we take $s = 1$ then we have the form $a + tn = 1$ where we can identify the $t$ with the $k$ in def $2.$ since they are both integers and the $1$ with the $[a]$ which tells us that there exists $s,t$ such that $[a] = 1$ or, equivalently, there exists an element $[b] \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ such that $[a]$ is invertible. A couple questions:

- Is this the correct logic?
- If so, how can I state this in a more "mathematically sophisticated" way? I find it difficult, thus far, to contain my proofs to math symbolism and sparse english (when necessary). I feel like I'm writing an argument rather than a proof. Any general advice on improving proof-writing in that regard is also welcome.

Comment: I changed $\mathbb{Z_n}$ to $\mathbb Z_n.$ There is no reason why the $n$ should be set that way. The line that says $$ [a] = \{b \in \mathbb{Z} \mid a \equiv b \pmod n\} = \{a + kn\mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\} $$ should be between just one pair of dollar signs or double dollar signs, with the $\{\text{curly braces}\}$ and the vertical slashes and the $\pmod n$ (coded as `\pmod n` included.

Comment: See [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290965/242) in the linked dupe for a proof of this basic result on the solvability of linear congruences.  As for your error, note that $\,\exists s,t\!: as+nt=1\,$ is equivalent to $\,\exists s\!:\ as\equiv 1\pmod{n}\,$ so "take $s = 1$..." is not a correct way to determine when such a root $s$ exists $\!\bmod n\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the correct logic?

Your defintions are fine, but I do not quite understand your proof. The
statement $[a] = 1$ is problematic because $[a]$ is a set, so saying that it
is equal to an integer does not make sense.

Perhaps you are trying to show that $1 \in [a]$, but that does not imply the
existence of an inverse. Keep in mind that $[a]^{- 1} \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ is the
multiplicative inverse of $[a]$ if $[a] [a]^{- 1} = [1]$.

As a side note, if you are trying to prove that $1 \in [a]$, we cannot claim
that $a + nk = 1$ by $as + nt = 1$ because $s$ may not necessarily be 1. For
example, $11$ and $9$ are relatively prime, but there is no integer solution
to $11 + 9 k = 1$ even though there exists $s, t$ so that $11 s + 9 t = 1$.

For a proof, I would do the following:

In general, $[a] [x] = [c]$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ if and only if
$\text{gcd} (a, n) \mid c$. I know this result as the Modular Arithmetic
Theorem, though I am aware that this name is not conventional.

Nevertheless, in the case of the inverse, if $[a]$ is invertible in
$\mathbb{Z}_n$, then there exists a $[a]^{- 1}$ such that $[a] [a]^{- 1} =
[1]$ holds. This is only possible if $\text{gcd} (a, n) \mid 1$ and thus
$\text{gcd} (a, n) = 1$, which implies relative primality.

Comment: I've never heard anyone call this "the Modular Arithmetic Theorem". There are many important theorems of modular arithmetic and this result has no reason to claim that name. It doesn't have a standard name, but it is sometimes called the  existence criterion for modular inverses, which is a special case of the solvability (existence) criterion for linear congruences (cf. linked dupe).

Comment: @BillDubuque That is good to know. Thank you!