# For which integer $c$ does $20x+22y+cz=315$ have integer solutions $(x,y,z)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> To find the integer values of $c$ for which the equation $$20x+22y+cz = 315$$ has integer solutions  $(x,y,z)$.

---

One observation is that $c$ has to be odd since $315$ is odd but $20x+22y$ is even.

If $y \neq 5$, then we  must have $c$ such that $\gcd(22,c) = 1$, then we can find $z$ such that $5$ divides $22y+cz$ since we already have $315-20x$ is divisible by $5$.

Can some one give some hints how to proceed with the problem?

Comment: Why there is a dislike ...sorry I can't understand.

Comment: Side note: It is possible to squeeze "For which integer $c$ does $20x+22y+cz = 315$ have integer solutions $(x, y, z)$?" into the title? Somewhat less explicit than the body, but completes the question. You'll have to decide whether that's worth it.

Comment: Don't know why there's a down-vote. I'm afraid many people don't explain them...

Comment: By the obvious trivariate extension of the [Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290965/242) in the linked dupe, it is solvable $\iff  315$ is a multiple of $(20,22,c)= (20,2,c) = (2,c),\,$ i.e. iff $c$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what the set
$ A = \{22x+20y|x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\}$
looks like.

Once you understand that, you can reduce this problem to which integers can be added to some element of this set to get 315. In other words, what are the elements of
$ B = \{315-x| x\in A\} $. Then any number which is a factor of any element of B is a possible value for $c$. And any number which is not a factor of some element of B, is  not a possible value for $c$.