# Test if equation allows integer variables

Tags: modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, integers

Sorry it can be silly but i am stuck and can't get my head around this.

I have an equation like;

$b = \frac{qc}{p} + \frac{p}{2}$

Now $p$ and $q$ are known integer values whereas $b$ and $c$ are the variables. How can I test on $p$ and $q$ that the equation allows integer $b$ and $c$?

Comment: If $p | q$, and $p$ is even, there are infinitely-many solutions for $b$ and $c$.

Comment: Scaling by $p$ yields a bivariate linear diophantine equation whose solvability condition is well known - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290965/242) in  the linked dupe, viz. $\,pb-qc = n\,$ has integer solutions $\,b,c\iff \gcd(p,q)\mid n\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks.