# Need help with number theory problem involving LCM.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Country A has elections every 4 years with its first election in 1997. Country B has elections every 5 years with its first election in 1994. When would be the first time that both the countries will have election in the same year?

Work so far:
I have arrived at the diophantine equation $$1997 + 4n_1 = 1994 + 5n_2$$ or $$5n_2-4n_1 = 3$$ Is there an easier way to solve this or is solving the diophantine equation the only way. Please give detailed solution.

Comment: As [here:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290965/242) $\ 3 = 5x-4y\iff \bmod 4\!:\,\ 3\equiv 5x\equiv x.\,$ See the first linked dupe for most known methods.

Answer (score 0):

By Bezout’s identity, for all integers $a$ and $b$, there exist integers $s$ and $t$ such that:

$as+bt=\gcd(a,b)$

Now, if $a=5$ and $b=4$, we get $5-4=1$. Now simply multiply that equation by $3$, giving $5\cdot3-4\cdot3=3$.

Thus, $n_2=n_1=3$

Comment: you can use ``\cdot`` instead of ``*``