# Show that the equation $5x = 3$ modulo 20 has no integer solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, inverse

This question is half of a larger question:
Show that the equation $5x = 3$ modulo $20$ has no integer solution but $3x = 5$ does.

I can show that $3x = 5$ has an integer solution in $U(20)$ by using the fact that the multiplicative inverse of 3 is 7 in $U(20)$ since $(3 * 7)$ mod $20 = 21$ mod $20 = 1$, the identity of $U(20)$.

Multiplying, mod $20$, on the left,
$$\begin{aligned}7*3x &= 7 * 5 \pmod{20}\\ x &= 15 \end{aligned}$$
Now, for the first part of the question, how do I show that there is no integer solution for $5x = 3$ mod $20$? 
Does it suffice to say that there is no multiplicative inverse of 5 in $U(20)$, so there is no way to solve the equation?

Comment: For the last line, no.  The equation $5x \equiv 10 \bmod 20$ has solutions even though $5$ fails to be a unit.  Beware false converses.

Comment: Anyway, start playing.  $20$ divides $5x-3$ and so $5x-3 = 20k$, and so....  [or just brute force it]

Comment: Every multiple of $5$ ends in $5$ or $0$ so...

Comment: $5x\equiv 3\pmod{20}$ means $5x=20k+3$. Now, for every integer $x$, $5$ divides the LHS and the first term at the RHS, but $5\nmid 3$.

Comment: $5$ is not in $U(20)$, because it is not coprime to $20$. So this is not an argument. The definition just says that $5x=20k+3$. This is obviously impossible, because $5$ doesn't divide $3$.

Comment: By [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3290965/242) in the linked dupe $\,ax\equiv b \pmod{\!n}\,$ is solvable $\iff d:=\gcd(a,n)\mid b.\,$
 Equivalently, it is solvable iff it is solvable $\!\bmod d\,\ $ [where it becomes $\,0x\equiv b\pmod{\!d}\,$]. $ $  Thus $\,5x\equiv b\pmod{\!5n}\,$ is solvable $\iff 5\mid b\ $ [with solution $\,x\equiv b/5\pmod{\!n}\,$],  so it is not true that $\,5\,$ is not invertible $\!\bmod 5n\,$ implies it is unsolvable.

Comment: But it *is* true that **if** $\,\color{#0a0}{\gcd(a,b)\!=\! 1}\,$ then $\,ax\equiv b \pmod{\!n}\,$ is solvable $\iff \gcd(a,n)=1,\,$ i.e. $\,a\,$ is invertible $\!\bmod n,\,$ since by above it is solvable $\iff \gcd(a,n)\mid\color{#c00} b\iff \gcd(a,n)=1,\,$ since then $\,d=\gcd(a,n)\,$ is a common divisor of $\rm\color{#0a0}{coprimes}$ $\,a\,$ *and* $\,\color{#c00}b,\,$  so $\,d=1.\,$ In modular fraction language: $\!\bmod n\!:\, $  $\rm\color{#0a0}{reduced}$ fraction $\,x\equiv b/a\,$ exists $\iff 1/a\,$ exists. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242) for elaboration.

Comment: In your example $\,\color{#0a0}{a,b} = 5,3\,$ *are* coprime, so $\,\gcd(a,n)=\gcd(5,20)>1\Rightarrow$ unsolvable, i.e. your argument *does* suffice, but you'd need to justify this claim (e.g. as in my prior comment).

Comment: @Dietrich Actually it is a correct inference in this case of a $\rm\color{#0a0}{reduced}$ modular fraction - see my prior $2$ comments.

Answer (score 2):

If you multiply both sides of the equation by 4, you get a contradiction.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).