# I want to derive a formula that gives an exact solution for a series of maths operations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Take all letters as integers.
Let m=ax+b and n=cy+d
For what values of x and y will m and n be equal, where a and c are relatively prime. Can we do this by getting the least value for m and n?
For example is m= 5x+3 and n=3y+2
m and n are equal to 8, for x=1 and y=2.
If we assume b and d are equal to zero, things seem to get simple and m=n=ac, x=c and y=a, but if we assume integers that for b and d when they are not zero, things get a bit tricky.

Comment: Please refer to the Euclidean Algorithm for first order Diophantine equations. There is a wealth of relevant content on this site.

Comment: If $d=b$, things are also easy. Then $ax=cy$, which has solutions $x=y=0$ or $x=c$, $y=a$ etc.

Comment: $m = n\iff n \equiv b\pmod{\!a},\ n \equiv d\pmod{\!c}.\,$ A formula for the general solution of this system of congruences is given by [General Easy CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242) in the linked dupe.

Comment: **Or** $\,m=n\iff ax-cy = d-b\,$ which can be solved e.g. by the extended Euclidean algorithm, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3290711/242)