# Two grasshoppers jump in opposite directions - find effective solution?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, word-problem

I took a test in number theory and modular arithmetic today, and one of the questions looked like this:

> Two grasshoppers A and B hop in a circle that is divided into 81
> squares. The squares are numbered from 0 to 80. Grasshopper A starts
> on square no. 5 and hops 15 squares clockwise with each jump.
> Grasshopper B starts on square no. 80 and jumps 14 squares anticlockwise
> with each jump. They always jump at the same time. After how many
> jumps do they bump into each other for the first time? (i.e. when are
> they on the same square for the first time)

I tried doing it like this:

Let the clockwise direction be positive, and let $0\le p\le 81$ denote the position of a grasshopper after $n$ moves. Then, the position of A and B can be found using: $\displaystyle 15n+5\equiv_{81}p_A$ and $\displaystyle 80-14n\equiv_{81}p_B$, respectively. Now, since we want their position to be the same, we have to find the smallest integer solution to the following congruence: $\displaystyle 15n+5\equiv_{81}80-14n$ which is equivalent to $29n \equiv_{81} 75 \equiv_{81} -6$.

This is where I did not get any further. I have no idea how to find $n$ (and using systematic testing gave 0 points). Apparently, my professor suggested rewriting it as a diophantine equation but that doesn't exactly seem easier. Any suggestion on how to solve for $n$ is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The next step involves multiplying both sides by the (multiplicative) inverse of $29 \bmod 81$.  How to find that value is a basic exercise in number theory, involving the Euclidean algorithm.  Does that agree with the topics you've studied?

Comment: No, it does not sound familiar. The Euclidian algorithm is familiar, but I do not know what a multiplicative inverse is (or at least we have not used that term).

Comment: How about finding the greatest common divisor of $29$ and $81$?  Are you familiar with using the Euclidean algorithm to find that?

Comment: A previous Question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3290711/using-gcd-bezout-identity-to-solve-linear-diophantine-equations-and-congruences) may help you understand the connection between the multiplicative inverse (Bezout identity) and "rewriting it as a diophantine equation" suggested by your professor.

Comment: "Two grasshoppers A and B hop in a circle that is divided into 81 squares." How do you divide a circle into squares?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't think the student is meant to interpret that literally, merely that there is a circle, on the circumference of which $81$ squares have been placed

Comment: @H.s, whoever put that question together should have taken more care with the wording. In math, we don't have to say kinda sorta what we mean – we've developed the language to say exactly what we mean, and we should get that achievement across to our students.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I understand that, but I doubt OP was the one who put that question together, so I just don't see the use in heckling them for it. And let's not kid ourselves; if OP were to express that sentiment to their teacher, all they'd likely get would be a flat stare and "you know what I meant, now go do your homework"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$5+15n\equiv -1-14n \mod(81) \Rightarrow 6+29n\equiv 0\mod(81) \Rightarrow 29n\equiv -6 \mod(81)$.

The inverse of $29$ modulo $81$ is $14$, so we have $n\equiv -84 \equiv 78 \mod(81)$.

Check: if $n=78$, then $5+15\cdot78 = 1175\equiv 41 \mod(81)$. Likewise, $-1-14\cdot78 = -1093 \equiv 41 \mod(78)$.

In conclusion, it takes $78$ jumps for grasshoppers A and B to bump into each other for the first time.

As noted in the comments, the key step was to find the multiplicative inverse of $29$ modulo $81$. This number, call it $x$, is such that $29x\equiv 1\mod(81)$. It can be found a variety of ways, the two most common being the Euclidean algorithm (already noted in the comments) and trial multiplication by each number from $1$ to $80$. Of course, trial multiplication works best when dealing with small moduli and in fact is often quicker than the Euclidean algorithm in such a case.