# Why is the number of common divisors of two numbers equal to the number of divisors of their GCD?

Tags: number-theory

I've searched a lot but I am not able to find a simple explanation. If you can, please explain it in an intuitive manner. Thanks

Comment: because $gcd$ means greatest common divisor

Comment: It depends on the definition we use for gcd. In the most elementary work, gcd is defined as greatest common divisor. Then we need the theorem that $d$ is a gcd of $a$ and $b$ if and only if $d$ divides $a$ and $b$, and any common divisor of $a$ and $b$ divides $d$.

Comment: More precisely, there are two concepts of $d=\gcd(n,m)$, which (and this takes some work to show) give exactly the same result: The first is that $d$ is the largest integer that divides $n$ and $m$; the second is that $d$ is the (unique positive) integer such that if $e$ is an integer that divides $n$ and $m$, then $e$ divides $d$.

Comment: The way to prove this is by using division with remainder (the Euclidean algorithm, if you want to be precise).

Comment: As a sidenote, the notation that we use to say "$d$ divides $n$", is $d|n$.

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshine 'some work to show' ? no this is obvious. I'd say the only non-obvious fact is that the Euclid algorithm gives the $gcd$.

Comment: I have no clue how much background op has.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- Consider a divisor of the greatest common divisor.  Does it divide both of the original numbers?
- Consider a non-divisor of the greatest common divisor.  Does it divide both of the original numbers?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\,\ a,b\,$ and their gcd $\,(a,b)\,$ have the same set of divisors by the following

**Lemma** $\ \ d\mid a,b\iff d\mid (a,b)\ \ \ $ [**Universal gcd Property**]

${\bf Proof}\quad\ d\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid  (a,b) = ia\!+\!jb\,$ for some $\, i,j\in\Bbb Z,\,$ by [Bezout.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/718833/242)

$\qquad\qquad\, d\mid (a,b)\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid a,b\ $ by transitivity of $ $ "divides".