# When does the Diophantine equation $ax + by + cz = d$ have a solution?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

$x,y,z$ are integers

I think the answer is if the $\gcd(a,b,c)|d$, but I don't know how to show this in either direction

Comment: Here's a start. Let $m = \gcd(a,b,c)$. Then $m|ax+by+cz$ so, we must also have $m|d$.

Comment: See [generalizations of Bezout's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity#Generalizations). The proof should be similar to the proof for the case of two integers.

Comment: @videlity Ok that makes perfect sense since it divides one side of the equation it must divide the other side.  Can I have a hint for the reverse direction? I need if and only if

Comment: @VinnyChase I believe the proof is a constructive one using the extended Euclidean algorithm/Bezout's lemma.

Comment: The condition is clearly necessary, and it is sufficient by Bezout's gcd identity, which works for any number of arguments (a simple, conceptual proof.[is here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/718833/242))