# Proof for any two numbers being manipulated with coefficients will equal the GCF? (Fundamental number theory)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given any two values of $u$ and $v$, there exists values for $a$ and $b$ that would result in the greatest common factor between $u$ and $v$.

$$\forall u,v \in \mathbb Z,\exists a,b \in \mathbb Z, au + vb = GCF(u, v)$$

This also effectively proves that any values of $u,v,a,b$ can be used, and will still be a multiple of the GCF, but I don't know how to prove the statement.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to MSE! Please try to use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions/answers. I submited an edit on your post to include it. Please also note that you will get more answers if you include what you tried to do to solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the set $S = \{au + bv: a,b \in \mathbb Z \}$. $S$ is a set of integers so it has a smallest positive member - call this $k$. So

$\nexists \space n \in S, 0 < n < k$

We know that $GCF(u,v)|u$ and $GCF(u,v)|v$, so $GCF(u,v)$ is a factor of all members of S. In particular $GCF(u,v)|k$.

If we can also show thet $k|GCF(u,v)$ then we must have $k=GCF(u,v)$. so $GCF(u,v) \in S$.

Note that if $m$ and $n$ are in $S$ then any linear combination of $m$ and $n$ i.e. $am + bn; a,b \in \mathbb Z$ is also in $S$.

Suppose $\exists n \in S$ with $n$ *not* a multiple of $k$. Then we can find $p$ and $r$ such that $n=pk+r$ with $0\lt r \lt k$. But then $r=n-pk$ is a linear combination of $n$ and $k$ and so $r$ is a member of $S$. But this contradicts the definition of $k$ as the smallest positive member of $S$. Therefore all members of $S$ are multiples of $k$.

How does this help you to show that $k|GCF(u,v)$ ?

Comment: Simpler: we can use *subtractive* descent: $\,n>k>0\in S\,\Rightarrow\, n-k\in S\ $ (vs. $\,n\bmod k\,$ above), which amounts to using the extended Euclidean algortihm for the GCD in subtractive vs. mod(remainder) form. I explain this more structurally [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/718833/242) This is a special case of using descent by the division algorithm in order to prove that Euclidean domains are PIDs.