# An example of an even numbers $n,k$ whose $gcd$ is three.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, examples-counterexamples

I am looking for even integers $n$ and $k$ such that $k$ does not divide $n$ and $\gcd(n,k) = 3$. Is this possible?

With the help of some online tools I tried, but every time I am not getting the desired result. Kindly help.

Comment: @Mark: $9$ is not much even, is it ?

Comment: Yeah, didn't read the question well. Nevermind then.

Comment: It is a little weird that you needed online tools. And after just a few attempts, you should have understood why this is impossible.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I was just trying to cross check. That's why.

Comment: Please edit the question to tell us what results you already know, e.g. do you know any of the named theorems in my answer?  (If you don't add such context then some users may close and delete the question, so the answers will be lost).

Answer (score 4):

Even numbers are all multiples of $2$, hence the $\text{gcd}$ is perforce even.

Comment: One should *justify* why that inference holds given that nature of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The *greatest* common divisor of even integers is even. Though this follows easily from deeper GCD properties it also has a simple direct proof. Suppose  $c$ is an *odd* common divisor of $2a$ and $2b$. By the Lemma below we infer that $2c$ is also a common divisor, so $c$ is not the *greatest* common divisor.

**Lemma** $\ $ Suppose that an odd integer $\,c\,$ divides $\,2k$. Then if follows that $\,2c$ divides $2k$

**Proof** $\ $ By hypothesis $\,nc = 2k.\,$ So $\,nc\,$ even, $c$ odd $\,\Rightarrow\, n$  even, so $\,(n/2)\, 2c = 2k$

**Remark** $ $ Alternatively it follows immediately from basic GCD properties (assuming they are known).

By the [GCD Universal Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1189430/242) $\ \ d\mid n,k\iff d\mid\gcd(n,k),\ $  Put $\, d = 2.\ \ $

By the [GCD Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/785544/242)  $\ \gcd(2a,2b) = 2\gcd(a,b)\,$ is even.

By the [GCD Bezout Identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/718833/242) $\ \ \ \gcd(2a,2b) = j(2a)+k(2b) = 2(ja+kb)$

The Bezout-based proof is less general than the prior two proofs since it need not hold in domains where gcds exist, e.g. in polynomial rings such as $\,\Bbb Z[x]\,$ and $\,\Bbb Q[x,y].$