# Proving a sufficient condition for the solvability of a linear integral equation.

Tags: number-theory

The problem is from Borevich and Shafarevich's number theory.

> Show that the equation $a_1x_1 + \cdots +a_nx_n = b$, where $a_1,\ldots,a_n,b$ are integers, is solvable if and only if the corresponding congruence is solvable for all values of the modulus $m$.

Frankly, I am at a loss of how to approach the $\impliedby$ direction. I would appreciate some hints to get me started in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: by [Bezout](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/718833/242) it is solvable in $\Bbb Z \color{#c00}\iff d:=\gcd(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\mid b.\ $  If it's solvable for all moduli then it's solvable $\bmod d,\,$  so there are $\,x_i$ with $\bmod d\!:\,\ b \equiv a_1x_1 + \cdots +a_nx_n\color{#0a0}{\equiv 0},\,$ by $\,\color{#0a0}{d\mid a_i}.\,$ Thus $\,d\mid b\ \ \color{#c00}{\rm thus}$ it is solvable in $\,\Bbb Z.$