# coprime polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

*Prove that if $f,g$ are coprime polynomials then there exist $a,b$ polynomials such that $af+bg=1$*

I think it has something to do with Euclid's algorithm, would like to see a proof.

Comment: If you know how to prove "if f and g are coprime integers then there exist integers a and b such that af+bg=1", then mimic the same proof for polynomials.

Comment: You are correct to assume that it has something to do with Euclid's algorithm, since polynomials consitute a euclidean domain, and behaves like integer. The name of the equation you wrote is (generalized) Bézoute's identity for polynomials. Concrete proofs can be found in **Kaczorek 2007.** _Polynomial and Rational Matrices_ (chapter 1 and 2); **Vidyasagar 1985**. _Control System Synthesis, A Factorization Approach (reprint 2011)_ (Chapter 4 and Appendices A & B); and **Polderman & Willems 1998.** _Introduction to Mathematical Systems Theory_ (Appendix B). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

By Bezout’s identity there
exists two polynomials a and b such that
$gcd(f,g)=af+bg$. If f and g are coprime then gcd(f,g)=1 and hence there exists polynomials a and b such that $+=1$ (It's exactly the same as the proof for integers: [Bezout's identity in $F[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364878/bezouts-identity-in-fx)).