# Use of Bezout's identity in Bourbaki

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

In "Groupes et algebres de Lie" in chapter VII  of "Elements de mathematique" by Bourbaki in Proposition 3 there are the following arguments:

Let $ P(X) = \Pi(X-\lambda_i)^{q_i} (i=1,...,n)$,
$Q(X)= (X-\lambda_0)^{q_0} )$,
where all $\lambda$ are different. Suppose that for vector space $V$ there exists  linear map $A$ and vector $v$ such that $P(A)(v)=0$ and $Q(A)(v)=0$. Because polynomials $P, Q$ are  coprime then from Bezout's identity it follows that $v=0$.

I don't understand what they mean under "Bezout's identity" and how it applies here.

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364878/bezouts-identity-in-fx). We find polynomials $R,S$ with $R(x)P(x)+S(x)Q(x)=1$. Now apply this with $X=A$ on $v$.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand.